# CodeIgniter 4: Autoload Library

Tags: php, autoload, codeigniter-4

I'm using the latest 'master' branch of [CodeIgniter 4](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4)

I have a Library that I'm trying to load automatically. Effectively, I want to have have 'one' index.php (that has meta, the basic html structure, etc) through which I can load views via my 'Template' Library.

My Library file: (~/app/Libraries/Template.php)

```
//class Template extends CI_Controller
class Template {

    /* This throws an error, but I will open up a separte thread for this
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    */

    public function render($view, $data = array()) {        
        $data['content_view'] = $view;  
        return view('layout/index', $data);     
    }

}
```

I also have a controller set up:

```
class Locations extends BaseController
{

    public function index()
    {
        return $this->template->render("locations/index", $view_data); 
        //return view('locations/index');
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

In ~/app/Config/ I added my Library

```
    $classmap = [
        'Template' => APPPATH .'/Libraries/Template.php'
    ];
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Call to a member function render() on null
```

What am I doing wrong that's causing my library not to load?

Comment: CodeIgniter 4 isn't released. It isn't good for production. Why do you use it?

Comment: Testing it out :)

Answer (score 12):

In CI4 the `BaseController` is where you create things that you want to be used by multiple other controllers. Creating classes that extend others is so very easy in CI4.

It seems to me that the only thing you are missing is creating the `Template` class. (There are a couple of other minor things too, but who am I to point fingers?)

One big item that might be just that you don't show it even though you are doing it. That is using `namespace` and `use` directives. They are must-do items for CI 4.

Because of where you have put your files you don't need and should remove the following. See how I've used `use` which imports `namespace` already known to the autoloader.

```
$classmap = [
        'Template' => APPPATH .'/Libraries/Template.php'
    ];
```

First, the BaseController

**/app/Controllers/BaseController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use App\Libraries\Template;

class BaseController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
     * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
     * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $helpers = [];

    protected $template;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function initController(\CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface $request, \CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface $response, \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

        $this->template = new Template();
    }

}
```

**/app/Controllers/Locations.php**

```
class Locations extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        // set $viewData somehow
        $viewData['someVar'] = "By Magic!";
        return $this->template->render("locations/index", $viewData);
    }
}
```

**/app/Libraries/Template.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Libraries;

class Template
{
    public function render($view, $data = [])
    {
        return view($view, $data);
    }
}
```

**/app/Views/locations/index.php**

```
This works as if... <strong><?= $someVar; ?></strong>
```

I know I haven't created exactly what you want to do. But the above should get you where you want to go. I hope so anyway.

Answer (score 4):

It's tricky at first.
But I managed to run it successfully

Make sure you give it proper namespace

And then just "use" in your controller Location.
I dont change anything on Autoload.php.

**app/Libraries/Template.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

class Template {
    public static function render($param) {
        return 'Hello '.ucwords($param);
    }
}
```

The proper way to call is put `use App\Libraries\Template` just before `class Location extends BaseController`

**app/Controllers/Locations.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Libraries\Template;

class Locations extends BaseController {
    public function index() {
        $template = new Template();
        $renderedStuff = $template->render('World!');
        echo $renderedStuff;
    }
}
```

**How does this work?**
Notice in `Template.php` there is a namespace `namespace App\Libraries;`, so CI4 will automatically load that library properly also recognize the "Template" class. That is proper way to create CI4 libraries in my point of view.

**How do we use that library?**
Look at my example of `Locations.php` and then see this code `use App\Libraries\Template;`, that's how we call that libraries.

**How do we call the function?**
Look inside the `index()` function, here we call class Template using var `$template = new Template();`.
Then we call `render()` function in Template library with `$template->render('World!');`.

Just as simple as that.
I hope thats help, lemme know if it doesnt works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a little hint, as my eye was hooked by the `CI_Controller` part.

You seems to use CI3 syntax within CI4, at least about loading the view, which translates to just:

```
$data = [
    'title' => 'Some title',
];

echo view('news_template', $data);
```

See the [CI3doc](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/static_pages.html) vs the [CI4doc](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/tutorial/static_pages.html) , the "static page" tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've just updated the code to prevent any confusion on that front.