# how to use my own libraries in codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm using codeigniter 4 but when I try to call my own library I get the error `Undefined variable: utils`.

here's my code:

**/app/libraries/Utils.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Libraries;

class Utils
{
    function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
        return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x='0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil($length/strlen($x)) )),1,$length);
    }
}
```

**/app/Controllers/Users.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use App\Models\UserModel;
use App\Libraries\Utils;

class Users extends ResourceController
{
    ...
    public function do_reset_password()
    {
        $utils = new Utils();
        $str = $utils->generateRandomString(); // the error points to this line
    ...
```

Comment: please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900176/codeigniter-4-autoload-library

Answer (score 0):

You should place your file Utils.php in /app/Libraries

[image: example project structure]

Do not create your own libraries directory in root project.

Comment: sorry I made a typo when writing the Utils.php location. after I rechecked, the Utils.php is already in /app/Libraries/Utils.php. I edited the path in the question.

Comment: do you have any screeshoot of that error? `Undefined variable: utils`

Answer (score 0):

In your use line what happens if you do this:

`use App\Libraries\Utils as MyUtils;` and call `$utils = new MyUtils` instead?

Please also make sure your Libraries folder begins with a capital L.