# Using Google api in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, google-search-api

I want to use google api in my CodeIgniter 4.

First I have downloaded and installed google api from https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

2nd i need to create library in CI4 library

```
require APPPATH . "ThirdParty/google/vendor/autoload.php";

class Google extends Google_Client {
    function __construct($params = array()) {
        parent::__construct();
}
```

}

Then i want to access in my model
model constructor code is below

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('google');
}
```

after loading library is showing error

Error
Call to a member function library() on null

please help how should i use

Comment: `$this->load->library('google');` is CI3 syntax. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58900176/codeigniter-4-autoload-library

Comment: You should use autoload mechanism in CI4 : https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/concepts/autoloader.html